# How to convert from list to String - java

Tags: java, string, list

I need help to make list from my Jlist jListpersons, and i want to convert that list to a String

```
List listOfPersonNames = jListpersons.getSelectedValuesList();
String teamName = (String)jListhold.getSelectedValue();
String[] personNamesA = (String[])listOfPersonNames.toArray();

con.createNewTeam(teamName, personNamesA[0], personNamesA[1], personNamesA[2], personNamesA[3]);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I don't see any question mark.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate that is aother Jlist where you only can select 1 team, and on jListpersons you pick 4 persons to join that team

Comment: @MarounMaroun my question is, how do i convert my list to a String and after that i want to cut the String out in 4 pieces whit 1 person in each String.                                                               In the Jlist it stands like this: lars,4,1,4,10                           peter,3,22,10,9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List listOfPersonNames = jListpersons.getSelectedValuesList();

// your list of strings
List<String> listOfNameStrings = new ArrayList<String>(listOfPersonNames.size());

for (Object personName: listOfPersonNames) {
    listOfNameStrings.add(personName.toString());
}

// your string from the resulting list
String listString = listOfNameStrings.toString();
```

If `List.toString()` does not give you the formatting you want, add the `StringBuilder`-based solution by @Stefan to turn the resulting list into a String

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : personNamesA ) {
    builder.append(s);
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

thats all. there is no magic behind it.

Comment: +1 for answering non existing question.

Comment: sorry I thought I saw the question(i want to convert that list to a String) :-)

Comment: Was writing the same thing, but you were faster. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try  [**Arrays.toString**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

```
String value = Arrays.toString(personNamesA);
System.out.println(value.substring(1, value.length() - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these line:

```
List listOfPersonNames = jListpersons.getSelectedValuesList();
String[] personNamesA = (String[])listOfPersonNames.toArray();
```

To:

```
List<String> listOfPersonNames = jListpersons.getSelectedValuesList();
String[] personNamesA = new String[listOfPersonNames.size()];
personNamesA = listOfPersonNames.toArray(personNamesA );
```

Comment: I tryed your code but, it says : incomptaible types: Object[] cant be converted to String[]

Comment: Sorry i missed one line earlier. Hope it helps now.